# wxWidgets (or even OOP GUI) Multiple Windows

Tags: c++, oop, user-interface, window, wxwidgets

I'm kind of stuck on something; regarding spawning multiple forms in OOP.

The message loop most of the time is (wxWidget's case) window->show();

```
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MainWindow *oWindow = new MainWindow(wxT("My Window"));
    oWindow->Show(true);

    return true;
}
```

**Others have oWindow->run(), but anyway my question is:**

I've created a second thread with the exact same structure of the function above and called the message loop method. The problem is that the window appears and dissapears suddenly which doesn't make sense to me. If however I call:

```
MainWindow *oWindow = new MainWindow(wxT("My Window"));
        oWindow->Show(true);
MainWindow *oWindow2 = new MainWindow(wxT("My Window"));
        oWindow2->Show(true);
```

It will work, but I don't want that as I will need to keep track of the windows I create and have them on separate threads. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run wxWidgets windows in anything other than the main thread.

*"GUI calls, such as those to a wxWindow or wxBitmap are explicitly not safe at all in secondary threads and could end your application prematurely. This is due to several reasons, including the underlying native API and the fact that wxThread does not run a GUI event loop similar to other APIs as MFC."*

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxthread.html

BTW, I cannot imagine any situation where what you want to do is a good idea.  There is never any ***need*** to tun windows in more than one thread.

A windows program is event-driven.  You can as have as many top level windows as you want, but there should be just one event queue so that the events on two windows do not end up  in contention for the same resource.  This is why wxWidgets prevents you trying to create two threads both handling windows events.

Comment: In WinAPI - I always have to create a new thread that spawns the window from the callback procedure and run the main loop. Why is this different?

Comment: Gosh, it is over 10 years since I used the WinAPI to create windows.  I remember it was painful, though I don't remember having to create new threads for every window.

Comment: I feel you. I'm working on a GUI intensive project and I've attempted it first in winAPI. Got only 3 windows done and not only that they look horrible, but I was wasting so much time on it. That's why I'm going with wxWidgets now. It's easy, comprehensive and fast (what I'm mainly interested in). Only a couple of things are unfamiliar to me like this question here. Thanks for your feedback though, I'll check that link :).